# JQuery Mobile: How to show a message while querying Web SQL

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I read all the questions about messages in JQuery Mobile but could not find a answer to my problem.

I have pages with lists where each list item opens a new page with the results of a query. It is all working correctly, but I during the query the target page appears blank untill the query is completed.
What I want is to inform the user that are a search in progress, but I couldn't find the appropriate position to put the function.

```
// in each li of list_a I have a href to page_b, that resultas in
// <li id="op1"><a href="#page_b" data-transition="slide" class="ui-link-inherit">Option A</a></li>
// <li id="op2"><a href="#page_b" data-transition="slide" class="ui-link-inherit">Option B</a></li>
// <li id="op3"><a href="#page_b" data-transition="slide" class="ui-link-inherit">Option C</a></li>

$('#list_a').on('click', 'li', function () {
    id = this.id;
    do_query(id);
});
function do_query(id) {
    //$.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg(); // doesn't work
    sql = 'SELECT ... ... ';
    db.transaction(
    function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql,[id], populate_page, errorHandler); });
}
function populate_page(tx, results) {
    $('#list_b').children().remove('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = results.rows.item(i);
        $('#list_b').append('result data...').listview('refresh');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of tests I found a intermediary solution.

What I would like is a spinning ball over the first page or over the targeted page. 
This workaround results in a message over a blank screen, but it's better than a empty page without information about the processing.

With this approach, the href in the list is not necessary.

```
    $('#list_a').on('click', 'li', function () {
        id = this.id;
        do_query(id);
    });
    function do_query(id) {

        // added
        $.mobile.changePage('#pag_b', { transition: 'pop' }); // transition slide fails
        $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("e","Searching...",true); // only shows the text
        // the ajax-loader.gif graphic stay static, doesn't spin

        sql = 'SELECT ... ... ';
        db.transaction(
        function (tx) { tx.executeSql(sql,[id], populate_page, errorHandler); });
    }
    function populate_page(tx, results) {
        $('#list_b').children().remove('li');
        for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
            var row = results.rows.item(i);
            $('#list_b').append('result data...').listview('refresh');
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

sounds like you should display the message however you'd like right before you call do_query(id) in your #list_a click handler.

for example:

```
$('#list_a').on('click', 'li', function () {
    id = this.id;
    showSearching(); //function to handle 'search in progress'
    do_query(id);
});

function showSearching(){
//show message however you'd like
//might use a jqueryui modal or something

}
```

but you'll also want to handle the hiding of that message upon both success and failure.
for example:

```
function populate_page(tx, results) {
    $('#list_b').children().remove('li');
    for (var i = 0; i < results.rows.length; i++) {
        var row = results.rows.item(i);
        $('#list_b').append('result data...').listview('refresh');
    }

    hideSearching(); //call message hide function
}

function errorHandler(){
    hideSearching(); //call message hide function

    //other error handling

}

function hideSearching(){
    //hide the search message

}
```

hope this helps!

Comment: I would like to use the JQuery Mobile `showPageLoadingMsg()` but I tried your method:to create a div just befor the div with the list

Comment: I would like to use the JQuery Mobile `showPageLoadingMsg()` but I tried your method: I created a div just before the div with the list and created the functions to show and hide the div. It doesn't work: the page with the link stay on the screen untill the query return the list.

Comment: if you're wanting to use the showPageLoadingMsg(), just make sure to bind it before jq mobile loads.  i found another thread on the topic that may help

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7028925/jquery-mobile-showpageloadingmsg-hidepageloadingmsg-methods-not-working-on-i

if that's a little unclear, then i'd be more than happy to explain.